# Estimating size of UICollectionView cell for some text

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextview

So I'm creating a messaging type app, which consists of some blocks of `UITextView` containing varying lengths of text and these reside in a "bubble" `UIView`.

```
let textView: UITextView = {
    let text = UITextView()
    text.text = "SAMPLE"
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    text.backgroundColor = .clear
    text.textColor = .white
    return text
}()
let bubbleView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 0, g: 137, b: 247)
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
var bubbleWidthAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

    bubbleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    bubbleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleWidthAnchor = bubbleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
    bubbleWidthAnchor?.isActive = true
    bubbleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

To set the height of the cell I am using a custom function which is <strike>supposed to</strike> not working properly.

Custom function:

```
private func estimatedFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)], context: nil)
}
```

Which I call in the `sizeForItemAt` function for `UICollectionView`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height: CGFloat = 80 //Arbitrary number
    if let text = messages[indexPath.item].text {
        height = estimatedFrameForText(text: text).height + 8
    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
}
```

The simple problem I am having is... it does not working great:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nhzz.png)

Any idea where I am going wrong, or a better solution to getting the estimated size I need for the cell, depending on the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, all that I was missing was to set the text size in the `textView`.

Putting `text.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)` in was required because the function to get the estimated size has:

```
attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
```

So you have to define both to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 updated answer is to handle height and width of uicollectionviewCell on the basis of uilabel

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
  let size = (self.FILTERTitles[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
    return CGSize(width: size.width + 38.0, height: size.height + 25.0)


}
```